# I Try To Integrate JasperReport with SpringMVC,But it doesn't work when print jdbc report

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

### This is My view resolver spring xml:

```
<bean id="jasperReportsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsMultiFormatView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jasper/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jrxml"></property>
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html"></property>
    <property name="jdbcDataSource" ref="druidDataSource"></property>
    <property name="reportDataKey" value="jrDatasource"></property>
    <property name="order" value="2"></property>
</bean>
```

### This is My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "report/jdbc2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String jdbcReport2(
        @RequestParam(value = "syudylsh", required = true) String syudylsh,
       Model model
) throws JRException, SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    model.addAttribute("empNo",7369);
    model.addAttribute("format","pdf");
    model.addAttribute("jrDatasource", new JREmptyDataSource());
    return "jdbc-report";
}
```

### The Right result is:

[The Normal Result Show Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luQ0S.png)

### The Right result Code:

```
@Test
public void testPrintPdf() throws JRException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    DBTools.initDataSource("datasources/oracle-scott.properties",DruidDataSource.class);
    Connection connection = DBTools.getConnection();
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("empNo", 7369);
    InputStream resourceAsStream = DBTools.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jasperreport/demo/jdbc-report.jasper");
    JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(resourceAsStream);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("d:/ireport_out/jdbc-report.pdf"));
    exporter.exportReport();
}
```

### Now Get The Bug result is:

[The Right Code Show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gHSz.png)

### I have config this in view resolever,but it seems doexn't work. who can help me?,help....

[Spring xml Has config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uKay.png)

Comment: Did you check connection? Is it valid?

Comment: yes,i sure the datasource can get connection beacause i have debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Now the problem has solved.

I have changed

```
model.addAttribute("jrDatasource", new JREmptyDataSource());
```

to

```
//datasource is db source
model.addAttribute("jrDatasource", datasource);
```